# Not all entries are shown via markers on Google Maps for EE

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

I have a problem with displaying all markers on a map.  My channel has 129 entries for dealers that need to be shown on a map.  For some reason only 95 are displayed via a marker on the map. 
The template setup is relatively easy

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="dealers" dynamic="no" disable="categories|member_data|pagination" limit="999"}

// all sorts of data about the dealer like name, phone, etc in a list

// the markers
{exp:gmap:marker 
        id="map" 
        infobox="true" 
        extend_bounds="false"
        icon="/themes/third_party/gmap/icons/pin-location.png" 
        latitude="{dealers_latitude}" 
        longitude="{dealers_longitude}" 
        zoom="8" 
        clustering="true" 
        show_one_window="true" 
        limit="1"
        style="width: '350px'"
        offsetY="-45" // Offset the X position of the window
        offsetX="15" // Offset the Y position of the window
        closeBoxMargin="5px" // Sets the box margin (could also be done in stylesheet)
        class="ui-infobox-dark" // Uses the dark theme made available by Google Maps for ExpressionEngine v3
        closeBoxURL="/themes/third_party/gmap/css/images/white-close-button.png" //Uses an alternative close button
        open_windows="false"
        //geocode="true"
        }


{/exp:gmap:marker}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It appears that -as expected- the javascript is not generated for the entries that not shown.  It is not random, so the problem is consistent.  But I really cannot see why those entries would be different than any others..

I’m running EE 2.5.5 and Google Maps 3.2.3

rg,
Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got response from the developer.  Thought I post it here too for others to use it. 
Setting

```
geocode="false"
```

does the trick

Comment: Thanks. This by far the most frequent support request. If I could do it over again, I would make geocode="false" the default, but if I did that now, people would have some real issues when they upgrade for 3.x.